# Converting rows from a table into columns in another table

Tags: mysql, database

How can I turn the rows of one table into the columns of another table using MySQL.
I'm making a beauty contest type of system.

The criteria table is as follows:

> ```
> 1. Mastery and execution
> 2. Audience impact
> 3. Stage presence
> 4. Creativity
> 5. Talent
> ```

And I want to make a table that shows

```
Candidate | Mastery and ex | audience | stage presence |... | Final
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I would strongly advise you do _not_ do that and find another way to structure your data.

Comment: @LolCoder Group concat and manually creating tables. I'm really not so sure on how to tackle this. I thought of making another table with the averages and then using info from that table to group_concat to the final one

Comment: @Ianzz it's not going to be stored for long, it's more of a view that I want to present to the php to make it easier for them to see the average scores of each candidate per category